# Android - Swiping the app from recent apps doesn't kill the application

Tags: android

I try to kill the app by swiping from the recent apps but the application is still alive. There is a singleton object that keeps the session information in the Application class. When I restart the app after swiping, this singleton is still kept. So there is still a valid session. 
This happens sometimes and not reproducible for each try. It probably(I'm not sure) happens after starting an activity with a Uri

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse("myapp://someactivity")
startActivity(intent)
```

Target activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="TargetActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp2" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="@string/url_host"
            android:pathPrefix="@string/url1"
            android:scheme="https" />
        <data
            android:host="@string/url_host"
            android:pathPrefix="@string/url_2"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I faced the problem on various Android versions (6, 7, 8).

Comment: How are you maintaining your singleton object?

Comment: It is initialized in Application onCreate.

Comment: is it a static field?

Comment: It is not static. But the problem is not with the singleton. Problem is that Application is not destroyed.

Comment: Any resolutions? i am facing the same problem with Android 10